# Read data from MI band 5 using flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a way to read data from MI band 5 directly to my flutter app. I have connected the band with my app using flutter_ blue but I'm having difficulties when reading the data and I have tried so many methods and they did not work. if I can get help for this matter it will be really helpful since I'm checking on this for my final research. If anyone can give me some resources to follow or give me some tips it will be really helpful.
any answer will be accepted and will be helpful.

Thank you!

Comment: What data do you want to read